# NEST is adding TimeZone while indexing docs in Elasticsearch

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I have a DateTime field in my c# class as below

```
 public DateTime PassedCreatedDate { get; set; }
```

While indexing it from NEST to elasticssearch, it is saving it along with local timezone. How to avoid this?

```
 "PassedCreatedDate": "2015-08-14T15:50:04.0479046+05:30" //Actual value saved in ES
 "PassedCreatedDate": "2015-08-14T15:50:04.047" //Expected value
```

mapping of PassedCreatedDate in elasticsearch is

```
  "PassedCreatedDate": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "dateOptionalTime"
               },
```

I am aware to have a field as string and provide the format in ElasticProperty, but is there any setting to avoid this timezone addition while using datetime field only?

Comment: Why do you want to exclude the timezone offset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things to change to achieve saving DateTimes without the time zone offset.

Firstly, NEST uses JSON.Net for json serialization, so we need to change the serializer settings on the `ElasticClient` to serialize DateTimes into the format desired, and interpret those DateTimes as `Local` kind when deserializing

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

settings.SetJsonSerializerSettingsModifier(jsonSettings => 
{
    jsonSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss",
    jsonSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local
});

var connection = new InMemoryConnection(settings);
var client = new ElasticClient(connection: connection);
```

Secondly,we need to tell Elasticsearch via mapping, the format of our DateTime for the field(s) in question

```
"PassedCreatedDate": {
    "type": "date",
    "format": "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"
},
```

Comment: SetJsonSerializerSettingsModifier doesn't exist in NEST 7.8.1 version :/

Answer (score 0):

For NEST 6.X and onwards,things have changed a bit.

Now you need 2 steps to achieve serializer settings .

1.Import NEST.JsonNetSerializer ,with a version identified with your NEST version.

2.

```
 var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, sourceSerializer: (builtin, settings) => new JsonNetSerializer(builtin, settings, () => 
                    new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                        DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local
                    })
                )
```

[refering to nest doc here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/6.x/custom-serialization.html#_jsonnetserializer)